# Botones de compartir en Wordpress meta og:image

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, opengraph

Hola soy algo nuevo en la creación de plantillas de wordpress desde cero. Recientemente he creado un theme. Quería añadirle los botones de compartir en linkedin y en FB. Quiero decir que cuando le doy a compartir nos solo muestre la url del post **sino también la imagen**. Lo primero lo he conseguido a través de una funcion y javascritp, pero no doy con el template tag correcto o la función idónea para incluir para hacer que la meta de open graph og:image funcione... Es decir que muestre la imagen del post. Esto es lo que tengo puesto en el head:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>">
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php is_front_page() ? bloginfo('name') : wp_title(''); ?>">
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php if ( is_single() ) {single_post_title('', true); } else {bloginfo('description'); } ?>">
<meta property="og:image" content="#">
```

Si alguien pudiera aconsejarme que meter en el `content=""` de la meta og:image lo agradecería.

Gracias!

Comment: Añado. He metido: <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url('', 'thumbnail'); ?>">, al inspeccionar codigo veo que me recoge la url. Lo que yo querría es que al compartir  a través de linkedin/facebook se visaulizara la imagen del post.

Comment: `echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url('', 'thumbnail');` te arroja el link completo de la imagen ?? es decir: `"http://www.pagina.com/img/imagen.png"`

Comment: Muchas gracias Camilo.. He metido el código que me recomiendas y va correcto! Debo tener algún problema con la cache puesto que sigue sin aparecer la imagen. Sabrías decirme como limpiarla?

Comment: Facebok tiene una herramienta que permite depurar el contenido compartido, es algo así como "permite vaciar la cache de los og", te dejo el link https://developers.facebook.com/tools-and-support/  después de que entres al link ingresas a **Depurador de errores de contenido compartido** y sigues las instrucciones, con linkedin no tengo ni idea como funciona puedes buscar si también tienen un depurador o si el mismo depurador de facebook te funciona para los dos